# How to make floating divs the height of the tallest element for each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of blocks of tables shown in picture.

The block has the following css

```
.block {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

And they are all wrapped within a wrapper

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div ng-show="condition1" class="block"></div>
    <div ng-show="condition2" class="block"></div>
    <div ng-show="condition3" class="block"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

1. Each block's height is dynamic depending on the content.
2. Each block can show or not show depending on condition. As you can see, it is possible that the second block won't show, and the third block will be pushed up to align with the first block.
3. There will always be at most 2 blocks per "row"
4. There will be alot more of these blocks in the future.

Now, what i want to achieve is for each row, set the the block with the smaller height to be the same height as the block with greater height. I am not sure how to approach this using CSS. If it is not possible, what would be the best way to approach this using jquery?

I spent countless hours and could not figure out (at least using CSS). All of the statements above are requirements and cannot be changed. Any expert help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will need JavaScript to do this.  Floated elements are taken our of regular content flow, so they are not aware of the dimensions of any elements before or after them.  CSS table cells may be a better approach.

Comment: How much control to you have on your HTML?

Comment: how are you not displaying the content through scripting code under a condition... or please don't let it be this through code adding a css class display: none or invisible etc.

Comment: @Marc Audet I have full control of the HTML but as for requirements I might not have alot of options. For example, the blocks have to be one wrapper cus the dynamic displaying of each block.

Comment: @muratkh I am using angularJs to conditionally display the elements. the conditions are not shown in the code because I think they are not relevant. ng-show="false" essentially translates to display: none. Or I can use ng-if="false" which just means that html block wont even be rendered.

Comment: the only way to achieve is either don't use float or use table like some one else mentioned

Comment: @muratkh i wanted to use table but then that would restrict my requirement 2.

Comment: @muratkh but thanks... thats a good idea, instead of hand writing those html blocks.. if i could find a way to dynamically generate those blocks it just might work.

Comment: I can think of one way of doing it but it involves some extra mark-up, but it would leverage the AngularJS framework.

Comment: @MarcAudet thank you =). Would you like to post it as answer?

Comment: I am thinking it through, the problem is keeping count of which blocks are active based on the condition.  For example, if you may have blocks 3,4,5 inactive (assuming a long list). You need to know how long the list is before you can style it.

Comment: @MarcAudet the height adjustment only needs to happen for each row though. Not by the tallest of all elements, but the taller element of each row.

Comment: Thank you but that might not even work to be honest because of the float. i would just say screw it and display it block make the width of row or table 100%. or make a media query to display how many to display at each break point if you don't want the list to go forever.

Comment: @muratkh it doesnt have to be float as long as it achieves the desired effect. I could try that. THanks

Comment: and i think you should consider flexbox like the example below that might just achieve what you need easily through css

Comment: flex is the way, but float + pseudos + faux column,  could, in a dirty way **fake it** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrYbNb and rounded corner too http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyejPq  ... don't mind it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to look at flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Flexbox can be used to stretch child elements based on the parent's size.

Here's a quick test I did in jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/7Lknyxqr/

```
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.block{
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  background-color: #343;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This works quite well actually, I tested it it with a various number of blocks and it is robust, nice!

Comment: This works perfectly! never knew there was a property as simple as this! Thought I would have to go through javascript and then measure the height of the next child or before child or whatever. THANKS!!

Comment: A few years ago, Flex was relatively new and not fully supported, but now, all modern browsers provide good support, so it is worth learning how it works!