# React - Dynamically set height of child div to be equal to that of tallest neighbour

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've got a container div, which contains child divs which themselves contain child divs - the layout can be explained by the diagram below:

[image]

The content of C is dynamic, and consequently so is its height.

I managed to get the B div's to all have the same height, equal to the height of the tallest B div by setting:

```
display: flex; 
align-items: stretch; 
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

on the A container as suggested here ([How to make floating divs the height of the tallest element for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148167/how-to-make-floating-divs-the-height-of-the-tallest-element-for-each-row)). However, I'm not sure how to get all the C's to be exactly the same height -
I want the C div in all the cards to have the same height, regardless of the content of C, and be equal to the height of the tallest C div (in the picture this would be the first C div).

I am building my site using React, therefore I am able to use React-specific solutions to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this problem, I wrap my dynamic div C in the [ReactHeight](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-height) component:

```
<ReactHeight onHeightReady={this.reportCardHeight}>
   <CDiv cardHeight={cardHeight}>
   ...children  
   </CDiv>
</ReactHeight>
```

I pass the `cardHeight` prop down to it and use it as follows to set the height (using [StyledComponents](https://styled-components.com/)):

```
const CDiv = styled.div`
    height: ${props => props.cardHeight && `${props.cardHeight}px`};
`;
```

Next, my `reportCardHeight` function dispatches an action which updates my state:

```
reportCardHeight = height => {
    const { setCardHeight} = this.props;
    setCardHeight(height);
};
```

This is used by my reducer as follows:

```
const cardHeightReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_CARD_HEIGHT:
            return {
                ...state,
                cardHeight: Math.max(
                    state.cardHeight || 0,
                    action.height
                ),
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Therefore when the content is loaded into `CDiv` the greatest height is stored in the state, all the other  `CDiv` in turn use this value from the state in order to update their own height.

Comment: I wouldn't track volatile UI related data in redux. Element height depends on things like the browser's font size and is not considered global application state. It's true that you need to coordinate the max height between different components, but redux is not the only way to achieve that. There's react context or you could have a simple ES6 module that tracks the max height in a let variable like a singleton.